# SQL UPDATE syntax update ID from 1 to 1000

Tags: mysql, sql

How to update data in column ID using UPDATE command

I need to update record from 1 to 1000

It needs to looks something like this without using auto_increment when creating TABLE.

```
ID || Column2 || Column3 || Column3 || 
1
2
3
4
...
1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @counter:= 0;
update table_name set ID=@counter:=@counter+1
```

It will update all the IDs and give ID as 1 to first record.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try something like this in the create command

```
CREATE TABLE T(

ID IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY

);
```

If the table is already created you can use the `ALTER` command to set an `IDENTITY`